# Change inner html dynamically from json

Tags: html, jquery

I have a json as follows -

```
{
"albums": {
            "abc": "ABC",
            "pqr": "PQR",
            "lmn": "LMN",
            "xyz": "XYZ"
        }
}
```

In the html structure below, I want that each value in the json should be added in each subsequent p tag (in the same order)

```
<div>
<p><p>
<div>

<div>
<p><p>
<div>

<div>
<p><p>
<div>

<div>
<p><p>
<div>
```

(The divs are NOT be appended dynamically). I also don't want to pick each p tag and set value of each key to it one by one. I want this to happen automatically when I call the json ( which is stored in a separate file)

I am trying -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("albums.json",
    function (response) {

    $.each(response.albums, function (key,value) {  

        $('p').each(function () {
            
            $(this).html(value);
        });

    })
    })
```

Doesn't give any output. Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by getting the index of the item from your values and using that to target the right `<p>`:

```js
var response = {
"albums": {
            "abc": "ABC",
            "pqr": "PQR",
            "lmn": "LMN",
            "xyz": "XYZ"
        }
}

var $p = $('p');
Object.values(response.albums).forEach( (value,i) => {
    $($p[i]).html(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p></p>
</div>

<div>
<p></p>
</div>

<div>
<p></p>
</div>

<div>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML isn't valid (none of `<p>` or `<div>` are closed).

```js
let json = {
  "albums": {
    "abc": "ABC",
    "pqr": "PQR",
    "lmn": "LMN",
    "xyz": "XYZ"
  }
};

let i = 0;
$.each(json.albums, function (key,value) {  
  $(`p:eq(${i})`).html(value);
  i++;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<p></p>
</div>

<div>
<p></p>
</div>

<div>
<p></p>
</div>

<div>
<p></p>
</div>
```